# How do I store analog input into the msp430 nonvolatile memory?

Tags: msp430, non-volatile-memory, energia

I am using Energia to program MSP430G2553 chip in a BristleBot circuit and I would like to store data in the nonvolatile memory, so next time I turn it on it remembers the inputs. How do I define this in Energia? I couldn't find reference on their website. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the Energia libraries all the time; you can access the registers of the flash controller directly.

But Energia also ships with the `MspFlash` library, which appears to be undocumented. Look at the [example code](https://github.com/energia/Energia/blob/master/hardware/msp430/libraries/MspFlash/examples/flash_readwrite/flash_readwrite.ino).

Comment: Thank you! Can I access the registers of the flash controller directly using C if I write my code in Energia?

Comment: Yes, if you really want to.